# Android ActivityForResult between 3 activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm banging my head for hours in this thing. I have 3 activity, the activity A open B, and C must pass data to the activity A. 
In activity A, I run startActivityForResult:

```
public static final int REQ_CODE_ACT3 = 2;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_ACT3);
}
```

Then B, passes the data to C.

```
Intent singc = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();                   
                singc .putExtra("cto", d.cto);
                singc .putExtra("colore", d.colore);                        
                singc  .putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(singc );
                finish();
```

Finally, C should pass the data to A. 
But the data are not passed

```
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra("cto", d.cto);
                 intent.putExtra("colore", d.colore);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                 finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: If B opens C then you need to have C pass the extras to B and have a call in B for activity result to pass the information to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- in A: startActivityforResult(B)
- in B: startActivityForResult(C)
- when C finishes creating result call setResult and finish activity C
- override onActivityResult in B and get what you want from C + setResult for A + finish activity B
- override onActivityResult in A to get the result returned from B.

If you need some example code, or still have problems, please comment.